# Convert NSTaggedPointerString to string

Tags: javascript, ios, automation, squish

I have an array of NSTaggedPointerString object obtained from a List View that I need to do some verification against. Specifically I need to determine if the string that is contained in testArray[i].includes('J');

Any ideas? I've done a fair amount of googling around and can't find anything JS related.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

According to a web search NSTaggedPointerString is a sub-class of NSString, therefore conversion to a script language string should work (and does work for me), as automatic conversion will take place then:

```
var s = "" + obj.text;
```